# Optimizing a Capacitance function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance, differentiation, calculus, optimization

I am trying to find the optimum values, in order to maximize the following equation:

$$ C (L, (b/a)) =\frac{L 2\pi k\epsilon_0}{\ln(b/a)} $$

where

$$ \frac{dC}{d(b/a)} = -\frac{L2\pi k\epsilon_0 \ln(b/a)^{-2}}{b/a}$$
and
$$ \frac{dC}{dL} =\frac{2\pi k\epsilon_0 }{\ln(b/a)}$$

How can I find this values? I cannot make these equations equal to zero. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The form of the $\frac{\partial C}{\partial(b/a)}$ is wrong, check your differentiation.

Comment: Sorry, I believe i have corrected my differentiation. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no critical points because this function doesn't have local minima!

The function is linear in $L$. To maximize, we want to make $L$ as large as we can.

Assuming $b>a$, the function $\frac{1}{\ln(b/a)}$ is monotonic decreasing. To maximize, we want the ratio $b/a$ to approach $1$ from the positive direction.

To summarize, if there aren't any other constraints in your system, the value of $C$ can be made arbitrarily large for arbitrarily large $L$, and $b/a$ arbitrarily close to $1$.